# React-native removed when use npm install

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install

I don't understand why my npm make that and i'm new with react-native.

Here is the description of my "bug" on Windows 10 :

I can use react-native command for run android or create react-native app like that `react-native init TestApp`

When i go into my app folder with `cd TestApp` and i run `react-native link` or other react-native command everythings work fine.

But if i install a new package like fbsdk with npm like that `npm install react-native-fbsdk --save` i saw after installation this message :

> added 1 package and removed 639 packages in 22.207s

And after that, if i would like use react-native command i have this message :

> Command `link` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

For this message, i have entered `react-native link` command.

You know why npm remove all my packages ?

Comment: Are you using npm 5 ? As per the [documentation](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), `npm install` will save it automatically to a `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: @Ksyqo yes i use npm 5. I have see a package-lock.json. It's possible symlink is the problem.

Comment: It seems like dropping a `npm install` erases the content of `package-lock.json`. Try to install without the `--save` flag.

Comment: I've tested but same problem, npm remove all packages.

Comment: add pakage.json file here to more clear you question

Comment: This issue made me start using yarn instead of npm. It looks like the issue started when I upgraded to npm 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem.

However I solved the problem by deleting the `package-lock.json` and then running `npm install`.

Check the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629309/react-native-command-run-android-unrecognized-maybe-caused-by-npm-install/44644191#44644191).

Comment: Using npm 5.0.3, removing the package-lock file seems to work for me too

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed recently that `npm install` doesn't do what I expect, but that may be because I'm newbie.

However `yarn install` is a good replacement and is working fine for me. I used it to upgrade/downgrade things by directly editing packages.json, and it also solved the `npm link` problem that I faced.

Edit: downgrading to npm 7 solved all my issues