# react-native: Command `run-android` unrecognized. Maybe caused by npm install

Tags: android, react-native, npm, npm-install, react-native-navigation

Recently I started getting this issue, when I install a react-native package 
(eg: `react-navigation`) into my project, a whole bunch of packages are been removed (including react, react-native i think).

And then when i try to run command "`run-android`", it says it doesn't recognize.

I recently updated to the latest `npm` and `react-native-cli`. Is it something wrong with "`npm install`"? or `react-native`?

```
node version: 8.1.2 <br/>
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 <br/>
react-native: 0.45.1 <br/>
react-navigation: 1.0.0-beta.11
```

Below are the steps to re-create:

> - Step 1 - Create project.
>     [image]
> - Step 2 - Run the "run-android" command (This works).
>     [image]
> - Step 3 - Install "react-native-navigation" into project.
>     [image]

```
Notice in the image above. Seems like all the other packages are removed from the project.<br/><br/>
```

> - Step 4 - Try running "run-android" command again. (will fail, but used to work before)
>     [image]

Any idea on what the issue is and any way to solve it?

Comment: do you have react-native-cli installed?

Comment: Yes @alejandrogarciarobles. I updated the question with version info.

Comment: Did you check if anything got deleted from react native inside node_modules?

Comment: Yes @Raymond . All the packages except for `react-navigation` (according to above example) has been emptied out. Very few files left in them.

Comment: npm install   command will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472878/npm-install-clear-the-react-native-in-node-modules/44476694#44476694)**.

At first running `npm install` didn't work, but then, deleting the `package-lock.json` file and running `npm install` did the job.

After that I installed `react-navigation` package seperately and it worked fine.

Comment: It seems when initially creating the project, and if `yarn` is installed, it conflicts with `npm` when installing other packages/dependencies later. That's why we have to delete and reinstall node_module packages using `npm install` (just one time).

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me from start to finish.

1. `react-native init NavTest`
   (The cli is locally installed with this command)
2. deleted package-lock.json
3. `npm install --save react-navigation`
4. deleted the generated package-lock.json
5. `npm install`
6. `react-native run android`
   A little ugly, I don't know entirely what happened, but this worked.
   https://reactnavigation.org/ for sample code to run.

Or Copy this to index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  AppRegistry,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';



class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Jane',
  };
  render() {
    return (null);
  }
}

const NavTest= StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavTest', () => NavTest);
```